# Redrawing a wye circuit

Tags: voltage, resistance, thevenin

Instead of using wye delta transformation I tried redrawing the following circuit but I do not understand where I made a mistake. The circuit appears to have the same voltage current relationships at the nodes, a, b, and c. I have shown all my steps to calculate the equivalent Thevenin resistance. Could someone explain what is wrong about my method of redrawing the circuit?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Pretty hard to read. What are the boxes?

Comment: They identify the nodes

Comment: Node labels identify nodes. Nodes don't need boxes to identify them. There are a variety of coloured crayons and pens available these days.